# File to import not found or unreadable compass - IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, compass-sass, compass, bootstrap-sass

I am  trying to develop my first page with bootstrap and SASS with IntelliJ Idea Framework. When I type in main.scss

```
@import "compass"
```

an error message is displayed:

```
cmd.exe /D /C call C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/scss.bat --no-cache --update main.scss:main.css
  error main.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: compass.)
```

I have enabled compass in intelliJ, installed compass using the cmd and set the config path for compass. What more I need to do to make it right?
Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

I spent a lot of time to solve the same problem. 
Go to WebStorm/Preferences/Tools/File Watchers.
There you should create compass watcher (press "+" sign to add new watcher) and disable SASS watcher if it exists! Compass watcher should look like in my screen. Try it. Hope my post will be helpful =)
[image]